# Linking back from the blog page/file

Tags: css, blogs, hyperlink

See **[this link for description in practice on Blog link](http://www.bcf.webitry.net/)** on navigation bar

Have installed the following **Blog** link on navigation bar of a website all contents of which is contained within the file **bcf_site**. The Blog script including its index.php is in the **bcf_blog** file which is in the main site file. This arrangement works fine on the navigation bar with the link to the Blog page as follows.

```
<li><a href="bcf_blog/index.php">Blog</a></li>
```

To navigate back out of the Blog file back to the webpages requires following this path: default>themes>bcf_blog>bcf_site>relevant .html page link on the navigation.

How should the following site navigation be altered so as to facilitate return to the main site pages:

```
<div class="topnav">
            <ol class="dropnav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
                          <ol>
                              <li><a href="comfor.html">Community Forum</a></li>
                              <li><a href="admincom.html">Administration Committee</a></li>
                              <li><a href="repcom.html">Representative Committees</a></li>
                              <li><a href="workgroup.html">Working Groups</a></li>
                          </ol>
                      </li>
                <li><a href="bcf_blog/index.php">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="assets.html">Assets</a></li>
                      <li><a>Issues</a>
                          <ol>
                              <li><a href="list1.html">List 1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="list2.html">List 2</a></li>
                          </ol>
                      </li>             
                <li><a href="lapr.html">LAPR</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>             
            </ol>        
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pfiew. It took me some time to struggle through your question, but my guess is that you just need to add `../` to all the links if you're in bcf_blog - in order to move up one level in the directory structure.

So:

```
<a href="index.html">
```

becomes

```
<a href="../index.html">
```